# Invertible compostion of 3 functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $f,g,h$ be functions from $A$ to $A$. Assume the composition $f \circ g \circ h$ is invertible. Is $g$ injective? Is $g$ on $A$?
This seems to be true if $A$ is a finite set, but is it true if $A$ is not a finite set?

Comment: @Surb "Let f,g,h be functions from A to A", so your example does not match the requirements.

Comment: A function from A to A is invertilbe $\Leftrightarrow$ the function is bijective $\Leftrightarrow$ the function is injective and surjective. Does that help?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Good point! Then $h=\tanh$, $f=\tanh^{-1}$, $g=\sin(\pi x)$ could be an example bijective composition and $g(x)$ could be redefined arbitrarily for $|x|>1$.

Comment: Some related posts which might help you: [Does $f\circ g$ injective imply $f$ injective for functions $f,g:A\to A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83622) or [Injective and Surjective Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22572) and som of the questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/22572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{(a_1, a_2, \ldots ) \, | \, a_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the set of sequences. Consider
\begin{align*}
f(a_1, a_2, \ldots )&=(a_2, a_3, \ldots )\\
g(a_1, a_2, \ldots )&=(0,a_1, a_2, \ldots )\\
h(a_1, a_2, \ldots )&=(a_1, a_2, \ldots )
\end{align*}
Then $f\circ g\circ h$ is the identity function, hence invertible. But $g$ (not onto) and $f$ (not one-one) are not.

**Note:** When $|A|< \infty$, then if a function $k:A \longrightarrow A$ has one of the two among injectivitiy and surjectivity, then it has the other as well. So, it works in the finite case.

Comment: @GyroGearloose $(1,2,3, \ldots) \xrightarrow{h} (1,2,3, \ldots)  \xrightarrow{g} (0,1,2,3, \ldots) \xrightarrow{f} (1,2,3, \ldots)$. Another example,  $(0,1,2,3, \ldots) \xrightarrow{h} (0,1,2,3, \ldots)  \xrightarrow{g} (0,0,1,2,3, \ldots) \xrightarrow{f} (0,1,2,3, \ldots)$.

Comment: Nice! This means $g$ is not necessarily on $A$, but is it necessarily injective?

Comment: by replacing $f$ with $h$, $g$ with $f$ and $h$ with $g$ we get an example in which $g$ isn't injective.